# Styling Open-Ended Text Inputs

Tags: html, text, user-input, styling, textinput

What's the best / recommended practice to treat a text input that contains HTML tags? The idea is to properly display the input e.g. on a different page.

As expected, people can be very creative with their HTML. For example:

```
<p>...</p>
<ul><li>...</li></ul>
```

Another example:

```
<h1>...</h1>
```

A more challenging case will be an input without a properly structured HTML e.g. `<h1>Hello</p></h1>`. Without proper care, this has the potential to break the whole page layout.

One thing I could think of is to completely strip down the tags. However, there might be a much better way. To the very least, I'd like to be able to place a proper spacing / margin between the paragraphs; instead of just collapsing them together.

Comment: `What's the best / recommended practice?` Not to do it yourself. For exactly the reasons you detailed.

Comment: @Jeff: Is there a SiteExchange site where I can (re)post this question? I still want to find out what others do in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Could you explain why you think the question is "not constructive"?  I'm a long time Stack Overflow user/contributor, and I've reread the FAQ, and I don't see what the issue is with this question.

Comment: Too bad that this question was closed. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rlb.usa noted in the comments, most people rely on a mature, well-tested HTML renderer to display HTML.  WebKit, Qt, and Microsoft's Trident control are popular choices depending on the platform.

If you've got a renderer that has problems with nonstandard code, you could run it through something like [tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) first.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't really clear on the description above. Some sites e.g. StackOverflow allow us to enter an open-ended input like this comment; and, we can basically add whatever we like <h1>Header</h1> but only certain tags are nicely styled e.g. `code`. Is that only a matter of CSS i.e. style some tags and remove others?

Comment: Yes, it appears I misread the question.  What you need to do is "sanitize" the input so that it can be safely embedded in the rest of your HTML.  There are libraries for this.  In addition to making the types of changes tidy would make (fixing up the mismatched and unmatched tags), a sanitizer will filter out potentially unsafe things, like JavaScript, iframes, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I think you meant unsafe JavaScript, not unsafe things like JavaScript. (:

Comment: @Siku-Siku.com: I meant what I said. Letting a user embed arbitrary JavaScript in your page is usually dangerous. Since JavaScript is a complete programming language, it's generally impossible to try to filter it for "unsafe" things.